# Getting Date or Time only from a DateTime Object

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a `DateTime` instance that has a Date and a Time. 
How do I extract only the date or only the time?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_members(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: try: 
var OnlyTime = YourDate.ToString("H:mm");

Answer (score 171, accepted):

```
var day = value.Date; // a DateTime that will just be whole days
var time = value.TimeOfDay; // a TimeSpan that is the duration into the day
```

Comment: `value.Date + ""` returns the `date 12:00:00 AM`. Use `value.Date.ToShortDateString()` to avoid this.

Answer (score 57):

You can also use `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` for the date, and `DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")` for the time.

Comment: Good call.  That's what I get for answering in haste.  Marc Gravell nailed it.

Comment: I'd say that you're looking for a string often enough that this answer has value, though.

Comment: This was  the answer I needed, because I had to have just the date in a certain format: `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Comment: If all you need is your timestamp's date as a string, that's the way to get it.

Comment: The problem with this is that users with different date formatting standards will get a non-localized DateTime format. For example, the proposed yyyy-MM-dd might be suitable in Europe, but will likely be confusing in the US. The "ToShortDateString()" method that was propsed by Shail Nautiyal should resolve this issue, and IMO a better approach.

Answer (score 35):

You can use **Instance.ToShortDateString()** for the date, 
and **Instance.ToShortTimeString()**  for the time to get date and time from the same instance.

Comment: This is great because it also takes care of different formats in different cultures.

Answer (score 21):

With the .NET 6 which added `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` structs it's now possible to get the date and time like this:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(dateTime);
var time = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(dateTime);
```

Docs:

- [DateOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0)
- [TimeOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly?view=net-6.0)

Comment: These are newer and I find it easier to work with them :) I was going to add this to an answer but you did ti for me thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

```
var currentDateTime = dateTime.Now();
var date=currentDateTime.Date;
```

Comment: you also can use  

`yourDateObj.ToShortDateString();`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
if dt = DateTime.Now;

var DateOnly = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);

Answer (score -6):

Sometimes you want to have your GridView as simple as:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" />
```

You don't want to specify any BoundField, you just want to bind your grid to DataReader.
The following code helped me to format DateTime in this situation.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  grid.RowDataBound += grid_RowDataBound;
  // Your DB access code here...
  // grid.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
  // grid.DataBind();
}

void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    return;
  var dt = (e.Row.DataItem as DbDataRecord).GetDateTime(4);
  e.Row.Cells[4].Text = dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
}
```

The results shown here.
[image: DateTime Formatting]