# How to get only Folder Creation Date in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I know that, Example: `DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\Example\MyTest.txt");`will return the date and time of a folder creation but how do I only get the `"Date"`Example `"2014-12-01"` or `"Decemeber 12,2014"` of the folder creation excluding the time?

Comment: Not sure why the fact that you got datetime from as folder creation is to your problem... Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097127/getting-date-or-time-only-from-a-datetime-object?rq=1. Feel free to clarify if indeed there is something special about getting DateTime from `File.GetCreationTime` method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `DateTime.Date` property for that, i.e. `fileCreatedDate.Date`.

Comment: And [`Directory.GetCreationTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Jonathan Amend Sorry for being dumb for asking this question, so the new result your saying would be: DateTime fileCreatedDate.Date = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\Example\MyTest.txt");

Comment: No, it would be `DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\Example\MyTest.txt").Date`;

Comment: If you want to get the actual date only as a string representation, use mybirthname's answer; something like: `string fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\Example\MyTest.txt").Date.ToString("yyy-MM-dd");`