# C# Code not returning proper File creation date

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the creation date of several .mp3 files, however wrong Dates are showing up, actually only one date is being repeated throughout the loop, I have done extensive research I really have however and I think it is a cache issue however I cant seem to make .Refresh work, I am using VS2010 my code is as follows

```
private static void Main()
{
    var pstFileFolder = @"C:\Users\Damian\Downloads";
    var searchPattern = "*.mp3";
    var extension = ".mp3";
    var serverFolder = @"C:\work\";
    int count = 0;

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(pstFileFolder, searchPattern))
    {
        string fileCreatedDatey = File.GetCreationTime(pstFileFolder).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        var theefile = new FileInfo(file);
        Console.WriteLine(fileCreatedDatey);
        Console.WriteLine(theefile);
        count++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(count + searchPattern + " Files found");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You're getting the `CreationTime` of the _folder_, not the _file_.

Comment: @mybirthname, I am not sure it is duplicate of the [linked quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259506/how-to-get-only-folder-creation-date-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Habib you are right it is not exact duplicate, but it is similar question asked from him today. You can reject my flag if you want, no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.GetCreationTime(pstFileFolder)` will return you `CreationDate` for folder, and you will get the same value back for all files. Instead use:

```
string fileCreatedDatey = File.GetCreationTime(file).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(pstFileFolder, searchPattern))
            {
                string fileCreatedDatey = File.GetCreationTime(file).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                var theefile = new FileInfo(file);
                Console.WriteLine(fileCreatedDatey);
                Console.WriteLine(theefile);
                count++;

            }
```