# C# database date type displaying time also

Tags: c#, database

I have a C# asp DataBase with a table named appointment. I set the Data Type for one of the value to be Date, but when I display the data on a table, it shows both date and time.
Is there anyway I can make it just display the date only?

```
StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();    
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select PatientName,AppointmentDate,AppointmentTime from [Appointment]";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        table.Append("<table border='1'>");
        table.Append("<tr><th>Pateint Name</th><th>Appointment Date</th><th>Appointment Time</th>");
        table.Append("</tr>");

        if(rd.HasRows)
        {
            if(rd.Read())
            {
                table.Append("<tr>");
                table.Append("<td>"+rd[0]+"</td>");
                table.Append("<td>"+rd[1]+"</td>");
                table.Append("<td>" + rd[2] + "</td>");
                table.Append("</tr>");

            }
        }
        table.Append("</table");
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal{Text=table.ToString()});
        rd.Close();            
    }
}
// removed two '}' chars, because they don't seem to be necessary.
```

I'm displaying the table in a placeholder in an ASP webform.

Comment: Can you post how you are displaying the field in your code?

Comment: @RossBush I have updated

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4097197/993547

Comment: `table.Append("<td>"+((DateTime)rd[1]).ToShortDateStrin()+"</td>"); `

Comment: @PatrickHofman Is is different because my database Type for that value i set it to date. So it shouldn't be displaying the time, but it is, so i dont really understand why

Comment: @Igor im getting this error Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group'

Comment: @Igor Thanks a lot ! It works just fine now!