# How to get date from datetime object returned by stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, object

I have a `datetime` object that I am extracting from a `datatable` returned by a stored procedure called in my `Asp.Net` app.

```
DataTable tableInfo = _dtMgr.GetInfoByID(uxGridView.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());
tableInfo.Rows[0]["dateOfEvent"];
```

It returns the following: {3/19/2019 10:11:0000 AM}. I am simply trying to get the date '3/19/2019' and have tried the following. No matter what I do, it still returns {3/19/2019 10:11:0000 AM}. Any suggestions?

**What I've tried:**

```
var dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(tableInfo.Rows[0]["dateOfEvent"]).Date;
//dt1 returns {3/19/2019 10:11:0000 AM}
var dt2 = dt1.Date;
//same
dt1.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy');
// too many characters in literal error
```

Note: These are all solutions I have seen in [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097127/getting-date-or-time-only-from-a-datetime-object) about extracting the date from a `datetime` object in C#. None of them seem to work.

Comment: `d1.date` wouldn't work because C# is case-sensitive and the property is called `Date`. `Tostring('MM/dd/yyyy')` wouldn't work because a) the method is `ToString`, not `Tostring`, and b) `'` is for *character* literals, `"` is for *string* literals.

Comment: Just use the DateTime method "Date" which truncates the hours/minutes/seconds and return the value at midnight at the start of the day.

Comment: If you know that format already, manually construct DateTime object by splitting the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

....

```
var dt2 = dt1.Date;
//same
var s = dt1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

It is working , your code has some syntactic errors.

Comment: Argghh! This was part syntax error. Oddly, I still could not get `var dt2 = dt1.Date;` to work. It still returns the full `DateTime!` However, the `ToString("MM/dd/yyy");` method worked, but only after I had converted to `DateTime` first. The datatable should have returned a `DateTime` object (and that's what it showed in my quickwatch), but instead only showed as an object. But that's the subject of another post. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: var dt2 = dt1.Date; It returns whole date - but time is set with zero values.

Comment: Yes. I have to convert it to a string to plug it into a textbox anyway, so the `ToString()` method makes the most sense.

Comment: dt2.ToString() becomes to "3/19/2019 12:00:00 AM" in your case date string format using is preferable.