# How can i catch only date from this 2020-06-19 02:40:10.000

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I wrote code to get dates from database that are older than today by 5 days
but not working

Dates are stored in db as DateTime  like this 2020-06-19 02:40:10.000

I appreciate your assistance thanks in advance

```
var ArTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Arab Standard Time");

DateTime ArTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Local, ArTimeZone);

DateTime Today_DateandTime = DateTime.Parse(ArTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt"));

var query3 = (from st in Db.Support_Teckets  .......
              where DbFunctions.DiffDays(Today_DateandTime, st.Created_Date) > 5
```

Comment: `Today_DateandTime.Date`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: [DateTime.Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Date or Time only from a DateTime Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097127/getting-date-or-time-only-from-a-datetime-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Older than today by 5 days*" - but you are comparing time part too. If you only need to compare date part then you can use the var `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` to truncate any time part.

I am guessing you do not have any error in your code but not getting the correct data. Then write the last part of the query as following:

```
var query3 = (from st in Db.Support_Teckets  .......
          where DbFunctions.DiffDays(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(Today_DateandTime), 
          DbFunctions.TruncateTime(st.Created_Date)) > 5
```

Comment: thanks bro i used your code but i got this error The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'

Comment: i am using pagedlist to dispay data

Comment: this is what i wrote 
                      where DbFunctions.DiffDays(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(CurrentDateindateform), DbFunctions.TruncateTime(st.Created_Date)) > 5

Comment: @Ahmed Glad that it worked for you. Welcome to the community.