# DateTime Format change after JSON parsing in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

```
{"meritSystemCalendar":{"businessDate":"2021-04-21T00: 00: 00","cycleCode":"D"},"responseCode":"ok","statusCode":200}
```

On parsing the BusinessdDate into a DateTime property, the value stored is "21-04-2021 00:00:00"

How to convert the property to "4/21/2020" in c#

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying a custom DateTime format when serializing with Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635599/specifying-a-custom-datetime-format-when-serializing-with-json-net)

Comment: What is the real problem> The value is **not stored** as `"21-04-2021 00:00:00"`. `Datetime` has no format, it's a binary value just like `byte` or `int`. It actually stores an Int64 tick count internally. Formats only apply when parsing a string into a DataTime, or formatting a DateTime into a string for display

Comment: I didn't downvote but there must be at least 3 identical questions each week. A simple search would find them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Date or Time only from a DateTime Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097127/getting-date-or-time-only-from-a-datetime-object)

Comment: When you convert a Strng to datetime the format will depend on the settings in your machine.  There is nothing wrong.  If you want a different format than you have to change the settings in VS to display the DateTime to a different culture.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods to extract the date from the DateTime variable.

**First**:
You can use the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` annotation above the DateTime property in your model.

**Second**:
You can use ToString() method to capture the date from the DateTime variable.

The code snippet for the second method is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ExportDTtoJSON
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> p = new List<Person>();
            p.Add(new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Ahmad",
                DOB = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1).ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")
            });
            p.Add(new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Khan",
                DOB = new DateTime(2022, 3, 4).ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")
             });

            var jsonObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string DOB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`jsonObject` has the JSON data, and you can apply your logic to that.